# Networking with an SSD and its benefits

Tags: ssd, home-networking

I have a network of computers that all have the same application which accesses data from one main computer.

If this data was on an SSD would its increased access speed only be beneficial to the computer with the SSD?

Comment: It depends what the type of data is... if it's many small files then probably won't notice any difference... if it's large video files, for example, the SSD performance may help with seeking the file data more efficiently than a mechanical HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the speed of your network.

A real world example:

- My Samsung SSD 830 (a popular consumer grade SSD) has a sequential read of 473.8 MB/s and a sequential write of 408.1 MB/s. An average of 441 MB/s.
- Various 7200rpm HDDs seem to get around 85 MB/s.
- My home network is getting about 5 MB/s (real world file transfer between two machines both wired to the router - although one is via a powerline adapter).

As a result, the bottleneck in my file transfer process is (by order of many magnitude) my network. Both the SSD and the HDD can transfer the file significantly faster.

If I could get over 85 MB/s on my network then you would see a difference with the SSD, because the bottleneck would become the HDD.

It was pointed out in the comments that my 5MB/s is rather slow and this is possibly caused by the (old) PowerLine adapaters I have which can only do 12MB/s (combined upload and download). As a result, download only would be half of that (6MB/s) so for my example I'm actually being throttled by the adapter not the SSD or HDD.

Having said all that, Big Chris did note that seeking would be slightly faster with a SSD, so the transfer would start slightly quicker - but it wouldn't arrive any quicker.

Comment: Doesn't this assume all connected clients use the same data? Especially when they're almost simultaneously accessing different pieces from disk, I could imagine an SSD helps a lot. Also, 5 MB/s seems very low for a wired connection? Even using wireless I get *much* more, I think. But then: I'm no expert at all, the question lacks any detail, and apparently the OP is satisfied since they already accepted this.

Comment: In my case I have an application which has tons of product and item information located one machine. That one machine has to be on for the others to access. The SSD would probably help the main machine if the application was on the SSD but other than that I'm starting to think it wouldn't affect the other computers that much because It's not running off it's own SSD if that makes any sense.

Comment: I'd expect exactly the opposite, @Crystalwolf. Once the program is started, it's probably in memory, so it doesn't help a lot to put the software on an SSD. But for its data, things *might* be very different.

Comment: @Arjan: My slow network problem could be caused by the reasonably old PowerLine adapater since it has a theoretical limit of 100 Mb/s (or 12MB/s).